# Parse JSON into an object

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, json

I get a json string/object from my server to my c# client.

This is the JSON:

```
[
{"PrintId":1,"PrintRef":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Header":"header","TC":"tc","CompanyRef":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
{"PrintId":2,"PrintRef":"39a10cee-7cb3-4ed3-aec2-293761eed96d","Header":"header","TC":"tc","CompanyRef":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}]
```

I am trying to convert it to a list of object like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Print> Get()
{
    var print = new List<Model.Print>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
        var response = client.GetAsync(route + "?" + GeneralTags.CUSTOMER_REF + "=" + new Guid().ToString()).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var strJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var strJson2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);

            List<Model.Print> items = strJson2["data"].Select(x => new Model.Print
            {
                CompanyRef = (Guid)x["CompanyRef"],
                Header = (string)x["Header"],
                PrintId = (int)x["PrintId"],
                PrintRef = (Guid)x["PrintRef"],
                TC = (string)x["TC"]
            }).ToList();                 
        }
        else
        {
            evError(new Exception(String.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase)), ErrorTags.PRINT_GET);
        }
    }
    return print;
}
```

But it errors on this line:

```
var strJson2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
```

This is the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.
```

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(strJson)

Comment: Hi, this did not work when using Raspberry Pi2 (with Windows 10 IoT as OS). I forgot to add teh Raspberry Pi2 tag. - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top level json structure is an array instead of an object. Therefor you will need to cast to `JArray` instead of `JObject`:

```
var root = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
```

If you just want to extract all objects instead:

```
var objs = ((JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)).Values<JObject>();
```